# local database won't update and doesn't show errors

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, dataset, sql-server-ce

Hey i'm new to this and from what i managed to pick up this should be working but it  doesn't update my **local** database.

I have a `TelemarketingDatabaseDataSet` that was auto generated when i created my local database, which then i dragged the table onto the dataset and i guess they're linked.

Now i have this code :

```
SqlCeConnection connection = new SqlCeConnection();
connection.ConnectionString = TelemarketingTracker.Properties.Settings.Default.TelemarketingDatabaseConnectionString;
TelemarketingDatabaseDataSet ds = new TelemarketingDatabaseDataSet();
// DataTable tbl = new DataTable();

SqlCeDataAdapter adapter = new SqlCeDataAdapter("select * from Calls", connection);
//adapter.InsertCommand = new SqlCeCommand("InsertQuery", connection);
adapter.Fill(ds,"Calls");
DataTable tbl = ds.Tables["Calls"];
//tbl.Columns.Add("caller");
//tbl.Columns.Add("called");
//tbl.Columns.Add("duration");
//tbl.Columns.Add("time");
var row = tbl.NewRow();

row[1] = Convert.ToString(caller);
row[2] = Convert.ToString(called);
row[3] = Convert.ToString(duration);
row[4] = Convert.ToDateTime(time);
tbl.Rows.Add(row);
adapter.Update(ds, "Calls");
connection.Close();
MessageBox.Show("Database should be updated!");
```

And please, i'm not intrested in using an SqlCommand as i prefer using DataSet.

Could the problem be related to datatypes of my table? it doesn't show errors to suggest that but i guess this could be the problem. my Table consists of :

> **ID** - int,key
>   **caller** - varchar
>   **called** - varchar
>   **duration** - varchar
>   **time** - datetime

**EDIT:**

Now if i uncomment the insertQuery row i get an unhandled error occured in Syste.Data dll.

Now even if i try to use a regular insert command i get no errors but the database won't update.
if this makes any diffrence after i close the debugging window i see an X next to the local database but it doesn't show any errors.

This is the command i've tried :

```
    using (SqlCeCommand com = new SqlCeCommand("INSERT INTO Calls (caller, called, duration, time) Values(@Caller,@Called,@Duration,@Time)", connection))
{
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Caller", row[1]);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Called", row[2]);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Duration", row[3]);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Time", row[4]);


    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: think 'ds' gets overwritten by adapter.Fill(ds); call .. try adding the row after the fill statement. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ycd1034(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: First of all, thanks and secondly it still doesn't insert the row

Comment: And no, it wouldn't be related to the data types.  You would definitely get an exception if that were an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well in the end i didn't manage to solve this, instead i used a remote database and regular sql commands.

Thanks for those who helped!

Comment: Look for a copy of your database in the bin/debug folder, it will have the data inserted

Answer (score 0):

The Fill() method "Adds or refreshes rows in the DataSet to match those in the data source."  The key part of this sentence being "to match those in the data source".  The row you're adding gets wiped out when you call Fill() because it's not already in the source.

I'm not positive, but I don't *think* that you need to even call Fill() if you're only adding new records and not worried about modifying/removing existing ones.  If you do need to call it though, it would obviously need to be moved before any new record insertions you make.

Comment: if i comlpetely remove the fill method i get `Update unable to find TableMapping['Table'] or DataTable 'Table'.` error so i tried updating using ` adapter.Update(ds,"Calls");` which elimanted the error but still doesn't update the database

Comment: Put a break point on your Update() statement and verify that tbl.Rows still contains the new row you added.  That will at least give me a better idea of where the problem is.

Comment: ... and I am assuming your table has a Primary Key.

Comment: Ya it has ID... amitd has gave some progress so no need for the breakpoint i think

Answer (score 0):

Try something similar to this..

```
string dbfile = new System.IO.FileInfo(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location).DirectoryName + "\\TelemarketingDatabase.sdf";
SqlCeConnection connection = new SqlCeConnection("datasource=" + dbfile);

TelemarketingDatabaseDataSet ds = new TelemarketingDatabaseDataSet();   
SqlCeDataAdapter adapter = new SqlCeDataAdapter();
string qry = @"select * from Calls";
da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(qry, connection);
SqlCommandBuilder cb = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter);
adapter.Fill(ds,"Calls");


DataTable tbl = ds.Tables["Calls"];
var row = tbl.NewRow();
row[0] = caller;
row[1] = called;
row[2] = duration;
row[3] = Convert.ToDateTime(time);
tbl.Rows.Add(row);
adapter.Update(ds,"Calls");
```

See the example here http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/Database-ADO.net/UseDataTabletoupdatetableinDatabase.htm

Comment: without `ds.Tables.Add(tbl);`?

Comment: adapter.Fill(ds) will fill the table in your dataset.

Comment: well this at least gives me errors so it's a progress. i get `Update requires a valid InsertCommand when passed DataRow collection with new rows.`

Comment: ah yes..added an edit to my answer adapter.Fill(ds,"Calls"); and adapter.Update(ds,"Calls");

Comment: Oh yeah, of course.  @eric.itzhak The table you created and added is totally different from the table that's being loaded when you are calling adapter.Fill().  You don't need to create the table in the code, because the adapter automatically does that for you.

Comment: like @BrandonMoore said.. you need yo use "DataTable tbl = ds.Tables["Calls"];" like in the above code

Comment: But i have done that as you said it still give sme the above error. should i specify an InsertCommand that seems wierd to me as i never seen it in any code example.

Comment: try moving DataTable tbl = ds.Tables["Calls"];  statement after adapter.Fill(ds,"Calls");

Comment: Still the same error, `Update requires a valid InsertCommand when passed DataRow collection with new rows.` Could this be related that i'm filling the data in the first place with SELECT statement though i don't really need it?

Comment: Well the syntax is wrong somewhere in that row, get an `the best overloaded method has invalid arguments`. i'm sorry for all the easy questions again im new to c#

Comment: @Amitd I don't think that's going to fix it.  The docs say that it will autogenerate the commands so long as you've set the select command.

Comment: Could it be related somehow to the `row[0]` item which i don't set as it's an identity column?

Comment: yes my bad.. i've updated my answer based on http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/Database-ADO.net/UseDataTabletoupdatetableinDatabase.htm

Comment: @BrandonMoore if it makes any difference, even if i use just a regular insert command it doesn't update.

Comment: What's the value of adapter.UpdateCommand say after you create your adapter?  Also, does the Fill() command successfuly bring in existing data (if there is any)?

Comment: Also, you confirmed that the table has an ID field when I asked if it has a primary key set.  Not to insult your intelligence, but just to make sure we're on the same page:  There is a difference between an Identity field and a Primary Key and a field may be one or both of these things, but when you say you have an "ID" field that doesn't necessarily mean it's been set as the Primary Key in the database schema.

Comment: And lastly, I also want to make sure you're certain it's not inserting anything.  How are you looking at the data in the database?  If you're using a simple select query in something like SQL Management Studio then there's not much that can go wrong there, but if you're testing by using some other piece of code you've written to get the data then perhaps there could be a flaw in that code as well.

Comment: Brandon ya it's an identity and key. and i'm checking if data was inserted in the VS as it's a local database i just "Show Table Data". And i believe it does as i got a few errors at first for the rows not having right datatypes so i guess the link is happening.

Answer (score 0):

just want to share this even the if the question is old

```
using System;
using System.IO; //needed for path.getdirectoryname() and directory.getcurrentdirectory()

string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Path.GetDirectoryName(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()));

AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", path);
```

Directory.GetcurrentDirectory() will output "C:/..projectname/bin/debug" which is where the temporary database.mdf is located

by using Path.GetDirectoryName(Directory.GetcurrentDirectory()) it will give the directory of the current directory thus moving one location back
"C:/..projectname/bin"

then use it again

Path.GetDirectoryName(Path.GetDirectoryName(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())) will give you the location of the root database in your project folder
"C:/..projectname"

then just use AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData()